# Are the files in /etc/sudoers.d read in a particular order?

Tags: sudo, configuration

Are the files in /etc/sudoers.d read in a particular order? If so, what is the convention for that ordering?

Comment: The sorted order described in answers is typical for other `.d` directories, too, like `/etc/sysctl.d/` or `/etc/udev/rules.d/` or whatever.  Suggestion: **make sure to use different leading numbers when order matters**.  Sort order of the following filename characters matters for order (for sudoers at least), but you should only use the same leading digits for two files if order really doesn't matter.  This helps other humans see what's going on.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From `man sudoers`, the exact position found with this command:

```
$ LESS='+/sudo will suspend processing' man sudoers
```

> Files are parsed in sorted lexical order. That is, `/etc/sudoers.d/01_first` will be parsed before `/etc/sudoers.d/10_second`. Be aware that because the sorting is lexical, not numeric, `/etc/sudoers.d/1_whoops` would be loaded after `/etc/sudoers.d/10_second`. A consistent number of leading zeroes in the file names can avoid such problems.

That's under the title: `Including other files from within sudoers`

```
$ LESS='+/Including other files from within sudoers' man sudoers
```

Lexical order is also called "dictionary order" as given by the values defined by the environment variable `LC_COLLATE` when the locale is `C` (numbers then Uppercae then lowercase letters). That's the same order as given by `LC_COLLATE=C ls /etc/sudoers.d/`.

The list of files included and the specific order in which they are loaded could be exposed with:

```
$ visudo -c
/etc/sudoers: parsed OK
/etc/sudoers.d/README: parsed OK
/etc/sudoers.d/me: parsed OK
/etc/dirtest/10-defaults: parsed OK
/etc/dirtest/1one: parsed OK
/etc/dirtest/2one: parsed OK
/etc/dirtest/30-alias: parsed OK
/etc/dirtest/50-users: parsed OK
/etc/dirtest/Aone: parsed OK
/etc/dirtest/Bone: parsed OK
/etc/dirtest/aone: parsed OK
/etc/dirtest/bone: parsed OK
/etc/dirtest/zone: parsed OK
/etc/dirtest/~one: parsed OK
/etc/dirtest/éone: parsed OK
/etc/dirtest/ÿone: parsed OK
```

Note that the order is not UNICODE but C.

Comment: thanks for command `visudo -c`

Answer (score 4):

From the `sudoers` manual (regarding the `#includedir` directive):

> `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d`
>
> `sudo` will read each file in `/etc/sudoers.d`, skipping file names that end in `~` or contain a `.` character to avoid causing problems with package manager or editor temporary/backup
>        files. 
>   Files are parsed in sorted lexical order.  That is, `/etc/sudoers.d/01_first` will be parsed before `/etc/sudoers.d/10_second`.  Be aware that because the sorting is lexical, not
>        numeric, `/etc/sudoers.d/1_whoops` would be loaded after `/etc/sudoers.d/10_second`.  Using a consistent number of leading zeroes in the file names can be used to avoid such problems.

See `man 5 sudoers`.

The lexical ordering mentioned above is the same ordering that you get from `ls` (or `echo *`) in the `C` or `POSIX` locale.

Comment: You can do `LC_COLLATE ls` but not with `echo *` as the asterisk will be expanded by the present shell, which may have a different COLLATE value. I mean `LC_COLLATE=C echo *` will probably fail to reproduce the correct order. You need to do `LC_COLLATE=C shell -c 'echo *'`

Comment: @isaac Correct.